# JMeter - Set unique id per thread

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, unique-id

I am using Jmeter 2.9 and have recorded a test plan through Badboy of Logging in and searching for an account(different account through csv data file) and loading the accounts.

I am trying to run it for 50 threads on one server.

How do i set unique id per thread so that its easier to track if something fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ${__threadNum} to identify the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Where do I add this variable in my Test Plan? as the tutorial mentions that it will not work in User Defined variables nor it makes sense to use it on the Test Plan.

Comment: Typically threadNum is used as an index for user names or sessions. You will have to give details as to what do you want track, easily.

Comment: I want to track each thread during the load so that it becomes easier to identify the issue if any issues found related to the thread.